# right way to delete with not exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to reformulate this query with not exists:

```
DELETE FROM stage_instance 
WHERE binary_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM stage_binary)
```

I tried this:

```
DELETE FROM stage_instance 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM stage_binary 
                  JOIN stage_instance ON stage_instance.binary_id = stage_binary.id)
```

And this:

```
DELETE FROM stage_instance 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM stage_binary, stage_instance 
                  WHERE stage_instance.binary_id = stage_binary.id)
```

And also that:

```
DELETE FROM stage_instance 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM stage_binary 
                  WHERE stage_instance.binary_id = stage_binary.id)
```

Are these correct and equivalent to the `NOT IN` clause?
`binary_id` in not an unique column, `id` is.

I believe the last statement is a correlated subquery, while the others are not.

Comment: I would say only the last one is a correct translation. The other two are not co-related with the outer DELETE but "mimic" this by doing a join. I am not entirely sure that is the same thing though.

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
create table team(id int primary key,name varchar);
create table player(team_id int,name varchar);

insert into team values (1,'team_awesome'),(2,'team_bad');
insert into player values (1,'alex'),(2,'james'),(3,'jack');
```

Try this:

```
delete from player where not exists (select 1 from team join player on player.team_id = team.id);
```

0 rows deleted

And this:

```
delete from player where not exists (select 1 from team,player where player.team_id = team.id);
```

0 rows deleted

Last statement:

```
delete from player where not exists (select 1 from team where team.id = player.team_id);
```

1 row deleted -- the right one

select * from player;

```
1   "alex"
2   "james"
```

Comment: Would be more informative if the query actually deleting was the last one in the sequence – how would second and third be able to delete anything that's already deleted?

Comment: does that looks good now ? if run statement by statement you can check it is not deleting.

Comment: Looks better to me, now it's obvious the first two don't do their job as data to delete *is* still there ;)